# Trying to display fields based on selected option

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I have the signup part for team and competition but what I am trying to do is when the user selects competition I am trying to display the promo code field and that field will only be displayed when competition is selected if team is selected it will not show the promo field, thanks for the hep in advance.

```
        React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {name: '', email: '', password: ''};
          }

          handleChange(event) {
            this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
          }

          handleSelect(event, index, value) {
            this.setState({type: value});
          }

          handleSignup(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.props.dispatch(signup(this.state.name, this.state.email, this.state.password, this.state.promo, this.state.type));
          }



          render() {
            return (
              <div className="login">
                <div className="panel">
                  <div className="body">
                    <legend>Create an account</legend>
                    <SelectField
                      floatingLabelText="User or Admin"
                      value={this.state.type}
                      name="type" id="type"
                      onChange={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}
                    >
                      <MenuItem value={"USER"} primaryText="User" />
                      <MenuItem value={"ADMIN"} primaryText="Admin" />
                    </SelectField>

                    <TextField
                      hintText="Promo Code"
                      name="promo" id="promo" autoFocus
                      value={this.state.code} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                      floatingLabelText="Promo Code"
                    />
```

Comment: Are you expecting the code you have written to show/hide the promo field? Or are you asking how to write the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render text field "Promo Code" conditionally only if state's type contains 'COMPETITION':

Surround the field with `{ condition ? <YourField.../> : null }`:

```
 {this.state.type === 'COMPETITION'
      ? <TextField
             hintText="Promo Code"
             name="promo" id="promo" autoFocus
             value={this.state.code} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
             floatingLabelText="Promo Code"
        />
      : null}
```

Comment: I also am trying to validate the promo code and I want to hard code the promo code in, the user has to enter that code and it has to validate, any idea on that?

Comment: i am trying to use the onBlur to add a function that checks if the input matches the desired word. but need a little help

Comment: This are already the next questions. Please ask those in separate question here on StackOverflow. Could you get "displaying fields based on selected option" to run as I suggested in my answer?

Comment: i have created another question as you said, if you could help me with that it would be great, and also yes thank you so much your answer did help

Comment: Great. I'll look into your other question too.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your help